# Where is Angel 06 being sent?

Tags: dialogue, behind-enemy-lines

In *Behind Enemy Lines* the Admiral gives a location for a rally point.

> I set IP Cadillac, Canada 1-5, Virginia 2-0

Has anyone determined where (Longitude and Latitude) on Earth this indicates?

Answer (score 2):

He doesn't appear to be giving him a latitude and longitude, he appears to be giving him a grid reference on the aviator's emergency map that he's holding.

[image]

Since we can assume that the map is at least minimally encoded, without the map in front of us it would be impossible to determine what real-world location the address related to.